# Comment l'élément principal de la phrase est-il désigné?

Tags: grammaire, phrase

Je ne sais pas trop où adresser cette question, d'autant-plus qu'il s'agit surtout d'une question de grammaire plutôt que d'une question de langue.

Dans la phrase: "Elle offre une bière à son ami", "elle offre" est l'élément principal auquel les autres éléments (compléments) se rattachent. Comment est désigné cet élément? Est-ce qu'il s'agit d'un groupe nominal, groupe verbal, etc?

Pour résumer, comment désigne-t-on l'élément principal d'une phrase.

Comment: Je ne suis pas sûr que designer cet élément (sujet et verbe) ait un sens. Dans cet exemple, le verbe est transitif, donc le un groupe qui ne comprend que le sujet et le verbe ne peut pas être coupé du reste de la structure (en proposition, par exemple) de manière cohérente.

Comment: Traditionnellement : Elle →GN ; offre une bière à son ami →  GV. Le GV comporte le verbe **et ses compléments**.  ([par ex](https://www.espacefrancais.com/les-groupes-dans-la-phrase-et-les-expansions-du-nom/#Groupe-nominal-GN-et-groupe-verbal-GV) ou [encore](https://www.cordial.fr/grammaire/manuels/GR_VERB.htm)).  En général on appelle le GN+GV une phrase (ici une phrase simple parce qu'elle a un seul GV).

Comment: J'ai oublié de mentionner ceci : toute question de grammaire française est bien une question qui peut être posée sur le FSE. On peut aussi demander sur le FSE des traductions en français d'expressions et de termes anglais (américains, canadiens, etc.) qui ne sont pas dans les dictionnaires de traduction sur la Toile (mais pas vice-versa, pas de traduction du français vers l'anglais).

Comment: Si on devait résumer cette phrase à l'extrême, il resterait "elle offre" (ayant supprimé les "détails" quoi? et à qui?). Donc "elle offre" pourrait être "l'élément principal", si on définit "élément principal" comme "ce qui reste si on résume (à l'extrême)", ce qui n'est pas a priori une trop mauvaise définition.

Answer (score 3):

Je répondrai partiellement à la question avec les mots qui servent de nos jours à l'enseignement de la grammaire du français à l'école en France<sup>2</sup>. La grammaire n'est pas une science<sup>1</sup>, elle se contente de décrire des phénomènes en mettant des mots sur des mots, de plus c'est une discipline qui évolue et il existe diverses écoles de pensée.

**Elle offre une bière à son ami** est constitué d'un groupe nominal (GN) : *elle*, et d'un groupe verbal (GV) : *offre une bière à son ami*.
Le GN est constitué ici d'un seul élément (on dit que c'est un GNS  parce que cet élément est sujet du verbe), mais il pourrait comprendre plusieurs mots (*ma sœur/ma grande sœur/la petite fille* etc.).
Le GV pourra encore être divisé en verbe suivi de deux groupes nominaux (l'un étant prépositionnel, l'autre COD). Le détail de l'analyse dépend du niveau d'enseignement auquel on se trouve, de plus ce genre de description n'ayant qu'un but pédagogique on peut très bien parler et écrire la langue sans avoir besoin d'en passer par là.

Pour en venir au cœur de la question : le sujet du verbe (*elle*) ne fait pas partie du GV, et le verbe (*offre*) ne fait pas partie du GN. Dans cette optique *Elle offre* ne constitue pas de groupe à lui tout seul. Vu le sens du verbe *offrir* il est difficile d'imaginer son emploi sans complément, mais si on remplace ce verbe par *marcher* on peut écrire :

> Elle marche.

et on a un GN à un seul mot et un GV à un seul mot, le tout commençant par une majuscule (*E*) et finissant par un signe de ponctuation fort (.). En grammaire on appelle ça **une phrase**. Mais dans l'exemple  *elle offre* ne constitue pas une phrase.

---

Quelques références accessibles sur internet :

Groupe nominal et groupe verbal :

- Sur Espace Français : [Groupe nominal et groupe verbal](https://www.espacefrancais.com/les-groupes-dans-la-phrase-et-les-expansions-du-nom/#Groupe-nominal-GN-et-groupe-verbal-GV).
- Sur Kartable : [Le groupe sujet et le groupe verbal](https://www.kartable.fr/ressources/francais/cours/le-groupe-sujet-et-le-groupe-verbal/48793).

La phrase :

- Sur Espace Français : [Les types de phrase](https://www.espacefrancais.com/les-types-de-phrases/#gsc.tab=0).
- Sur Maxicours : [La phrase verbale et la phrase non verbale](https://www.maxicours.com/se/cours/la-phrase-verbale-et-la-phrase-non-verbale/).
- Dans le [manuel destiné à la préparation du concours de professeur des écoles](https://www.dunod.com/prepas-concours/concours-professeur-ecoles-francais-ecrit-crpe-2023) : [phrase simple et phrase complexe](https://www.dunod.com/prepas-concours/concours-professeur-ecoles-francais-ecrit-crpe-2023).
- *La nouvelle grammaire française*, ([p. 72, 73](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Nouvelle_grammaire_fran%C3%A7aise/OcuzBXD1p_UC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22phrase%20simple%22&pg=PA72&printsec=frontcover). Grevisse et Goosse, 1995).

On peut aussi consulter [*La grammaire du français – Terminologie grammaticale*](https://eduscol.education.fr/document/1872/download) dans les [Les guides fondamentaux pour enseigner](https://eduscol.education.fr/3107/guides-fondamentaux-pour-l-enseignement) du Ministère de l'Éducation nationale.

---

<sup><sup>1.</sup>  Je sais que je partage cet avis avec beaucoup de gens, mais je sais aussi que certains grammairiens disent que la grammaire est une science.</sup>
<sup><sup>2.</sup>  L'enseignement de la grammaire en FLE peut utiliser d'autres termes selon le public, l'origine des apprenants...</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Il n'existe pas de conception de la phrase dans laquelle entrerait l'idée d'élément principal. Ni le sujet ni le verbe n'est considéré comme principal élément : une phrase sans sujet n'est pas une phrase et de même pour le verbe ; les deux ne vont pas l'un sans l'autre. Lorsqu'on cherche à analyser ce qu'est une phrase, le point de vue le plus fondamental consiste à voir dans une phrase simple deux éléments ; c'est à dire que selon ce point de vue elle est constituée de deux choses, qui sont le sujet et le prédicat, le prédicat comprenant le verbe. Le prédicat est aussi appelé "*syntagme verbal*".

> ([Wikipédia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%A9dicat_(linguistique))) Selon l’une des interprétations, le prédicat est un syntagme verbal, qu’il soit constitué d’un verbe seul, ou de celui-ci et d’un ou plusieurs éléments qui lui sont subordonnés. Par exemple, dans la phrase Pierre écrit une lettre à sa mère, le prédicat serait toute la partie de la phrase qui suit le sujet Pierre. Dans cette interprétation, dans une phrase isolée comme celle-ci, le prédicat est équivalent, du point de vue logique, à la partie d’une phrase appelée rhème, commentaire ou propos, c’est-à-dire ce qu’on dit du sujet, qui est, dans ce cas, le thème, c’est-à-dire ce dont on parle.

[thème](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th%C3%A8me_(linguistique))

[groupe nominal](https://www.scribbr.fr/elements-linguistiques/groupe-nominal/)

[groupe verbal](https://www.scribbr.fr/elements-linguistiques/le-groupe-verbal/)

« Elle » est donc le sujet (thème) et « offre une bière à son ami » est le prédicat (rhème).

Comment: En grammaire on parle de phrases verbales (cad qui comporte un GV) et de phrases non verbales (cad sans verbe conjugué). Voir par ex. [ici](https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-121578.php) [ou](https://www.assistancescolaire.com/eleve/6e/francais/reviser-une-notion/6fps02) ou n'importe quelle grammaire scolaire.

Comment: @None Je ne pense qu'il faille faire cette distinction ; par exemple « Attention chutes de neige » n'est qu'une phrase dans laquelle il y a une ellipse du verbe. De plus c'est une catégorie grammaticale qui a très peu d'incidence dans la langue. Ce sont deux raisons, il me semble, pour ne pas en faire une catégorie sur la même base que la phrase selon l'idée traditionnelle que l'on en a.

Comment: En gros, ce que vous dite c'est que si ont doit considérer un élément principal dans tout ça, ce n'est pas "elle offre" mais offre en lui-même, + sa subordonné donc le prédicat, et le sujet en début de phrase, mais pourtant c'est le verbe qui se rattache au sujet, pas l'inverse, non?

Comment: @LPH Je ne donne pas ici mon avis personnel (qui importe peu en occurrence) mais je décris un état de fait qui reflète ce qui est enseigné à l'école dans la mesure où la forme de la question peut faire penser à un exercise scolaire. Et si c'est le cas il vaut mieux ne pas être trop catégorique et ouvrir le champ des possibles. Ensuite chacun est libre de ses opinions en ce domaine. Un élève qui dirait  qu'une « phrase sans sujet n'est pas une phrase » risque d'avoir des remarques de la part de son professeur !

Comment: @None Il auraient introduit cette idée dans les programmes ? Je n'ai jamais étudié ça, c'est d'origine récente.

Comment: @FMB Non, pas du tout ; ce que j'affirme c'est qu'il n'existe pas de point de vue grammatical, ou plus généralement, linguistique, selon lequel on puisse parler d'élément principal dans la phrase. Un sujet tout seul ne sert en rien à communiquer de l'information, et de même pour un verbe. Je ne parle )as bien sûr des cas d'ellipse (« —Qui est entré le dernier ? —Jean ! »)

Comment: @LPH Pas récent du tout. Moi j'ai toujours connu ça (j'étais à l'école primaire il y a très très très longtemps). Je parlais de grammaire scolaire mais je lis à l'instant dans *Le Bon Usage* (bien au-dessus de la grammaire scolaire) « Quand la phrase est composé d'un sujet et d'un complément prédicatif, sans verbe réel, les linguistes l'appellent phrase nominale (par opposition à la phrase verbale, comprenant un verbe réel) ». Et si on veut citer encore wikipedia : https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrase#Phrase_nominale

Comment: @None « phrase nominale » n'est pas dans _Le Bon Usage_ de  l'édition  de 2008 et dans cette édition il est dit  aussi qu'il y a beaucoup de définitions de la phrase ; c'est bien  une introduction d'origine récente chez Grevisse et Goosse. Les grammairiens ne sont pas d'accord sur une définition unique.

Comment: @LPH Mon exemplaire du *Bon Usage* date de **1975**.

Comment: @None C'est vraiment bizarre… Au lieu de l'avoir ajouté ils l'auraient retiré !

Comment: @LPH La décomposition en thème/rhème est sans doute possible, mais ne s'aligne pas très bien avec la façon dont on comprend habituellement les phrases Françaises ayant une structure "S-V-O" par opposition à des langues telles que le Japonais, où la décomposition thème/rhème s'impose beaucoup plus nettement.

Comment: @LPH *Grammaire Larousse du français contemporain* (ressortie de mes cartons, 1964) ): Dans le paragraphe sur la  phrase simple à un seul élément on trouve parmi les exemples, des phrases à un seul verbe bien sûr (impératif) mais aussi ***Curieux!bizarre...*** / ***Sot !*** /  ***Qui ?***  ***moi ?*** /.  Il y a aussi la [Nouvelle grammaire française](https://www.google.fr/books/edition/Nouvelle_grammaire_fran%C3%A7aise/OcuzBXD1p_UC?hl=fr&gbpv=1&dq=%22phrase+simple%22&pg=PA72&printsec=frontcover) plus récente, Grevisse et Goosse, 1995).

Comment: Mais c'est encore d'actualité puisque on peut lire dans [l'ouvrage destiné aux candidats au concours de professeur des écoles](https://www.dunod.com/prepas-concours/concours-professeur-ecoles-francais-ecrit-crpe-2023) : « On distingue traditionnellement entre phrase verbale (comprenant un verbe conjugué) et phrase non verbale (ne comprenant pas de verbe conjugué). »